# Removing old Exchange server

Tags: exchange-2010, exchange-2003, exchange

We migrated an Exchange 2003 to exchange 2010 running on a new Windows Server 2008 R2.
The old Windows Server 2003 with Exchange 2003 does not (physically :-)) exist anymore.

On my Exchange Server I saw event id 5006 MSEchangeTransport. When running the Get-ExchangeServer cmdlet I still saw the old exchange server which doesn't exist anymore.

I've followed these steps (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/833396) to go to CN=Configuration, DC=Domain_Name,DC=com, CN=Services .... CN=Servers

Now I see on the **CN=First Administrative Group > CN=Servers**   the old server as only server listed
and on the **CN=Exchange Administrative Group > CN=Servers**   I see the existing server as the only server listed.

Can I just remove that old server from the **CN=Frist Administrative Group > CN=Servers**  or should the new server also exist in the First Administrative Group instead of only in the Exchange Administrative Group?

I'm using ADSI Edit on the Domain Controller, I suppose that there is no difference on using it here or on the Exchange Server itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just delete the old server. The new server should not exist in both places, just its current location.

It doesn't matter where you run adsiedit from.

Comment: thanks. I had to use some extra cmdlets on the exchange server like "Update-Recipient" because something was pointing to a deleted object in AD.